# AWS S3 basic Usage Report - recent operations not included?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've noticed that when you generate the AWS Usage Report (the basic old type as referenced here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report.html), there is a delay between the operations taking place and them being included in the report. For example, if I create a S3 bucket using the console and 3-5 minutes later download the report, the operation CreateBucket won't be included in the file. It will appear only if I download the report several hours later.

I would like to know if such delay is normal, or is there something wrong with my settings? I apologize if this is something obvious but after searching all around the internet I could not find any info about expected delay in generating reports.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. From the [AWS Billing documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html):

> AWS delivers the report files to an Amazon S3 bucket that you specify in your account and updates the report up to three times a day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I was asking about the legacy AWS Usage Report that you can download as CSV file directly to disk from Other Reports section, not the Cost and Usage Report that you have to set up and is delivered to the S3 bucket. I guess that when it comes to updating contents probably the same rule applies though.

Comment: Good catch. As I'm not aware of specific documentation for the legacy usage reports, I assume that they're already that legacy that AWS doesn't even bother anymore documenting them properly. That said I think it's safe to assume that such older reports won't get generated more often than the current kind of reports.